# What could be possible causes behind intermittent ReferenceError/TypeError in browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

We have a web application that renders HTML pages and includes some external JavaScript files which define variables like `jQuery`, `$`, `app` etc.

We track client-side JavaScript errors in Bugsnag and sometimes we receive errors like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` or `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: app`.

What could be possible causes behind this? Two that I can guess are: user might have clicked "Stop" in browser and JS files didn't completely load but inline JavaScript within page was still executed (is that possible?), or some JavaScript files were blocked by a browser plugin/extension.

We have observed it happening in all major browsers (Firefox/Chrome/Safari etc.), but its **occurrence is quite rare** - usually once in thousands of requests.

Here is the excerpt from page:

```
<script src="https://path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { ... });
  // ^^^^ I receive the error here
  app.init(function() { ... });
  // ^^^^ and sometimes I receive the error here
</script>
```

Comment: Those errors are impossible to debug without a sample that reproduces the issue... The error messages themselves are very clear, but there's nothing we can tell you other than that.

Comment: I'm just interested in knowing "possible" causes (that can be generalised for any web page) that may throw this error and whether or not my two hypothesises could be true.

Comment: Those error messages are as general as they get: For some reason, the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: "For some reason" <-- I'm interested in knowing what could be those possible "reasons" specially when it works 99+% of the time and is very likely not an issue with the code itself. I've also added a code sample in question on your recommendation.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

One plausible explanation is that certain browser extension is blocking those scripts from loading (e.g., an ad blocker).